# Error: Requested entity was not found. at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor]

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-admin

when do firebase push notification

```
firebaseAdmin.messaging().sendMulticast(message)
```

I get and error

```
 // Error: Requested entity was not found. at FirebaseMessagingError.FirebaseError [as constructor]
 // code: "messaging/registration-token-not-registered", message: "Requested entity was not found."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer try **new** client registration token, and get fresh registration token from your client

> The provided registration token is no longer registered.

Docs source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin

Comment: I was trying to delete the token with `deleteToken` method but getting the following error:
FirebaseError: Messaging: A problem occurred while unsubscribing the user from FCM: Requested entity was not found. (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed). (messaging/token-unsubscribe-failed